# Creating a three dimensional struct array on the heap in c

Tags: c, visual-c++, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc

I am trying to create a three dimensional struct array using `malloc` in c on MSVC. It compiles without error but when i debug it it gives an error after initializing some elements.

declaration:

```
typedef struct table_info
{
    unsigned long size;
    char code[33];
    char path[300];
}table_info;
```

`table` is a global variable and is defined as:

```
struct table_info ***table=NULL;
```

`malloc` and initialize `table`:

```
char garb[33] = { '\0' };
char garb_path[300] = { '\0' };

table = (table_info***)malloc(ROWS* sizeof(**table));

for (int m = 0; m < ROWS; m++)
{
    table[m] = (table_info**)malloc(COLS* sizeof(*table[m]));
    for (int j = 0; j < COLS; ++j)
    {
        table[m][j] = (table_info*)malloc(DEPTH * sizeof(table[m][j]));
        for (int k = 0; k < DEPTH; ++k)
        {
            table[m][j][k].size = 0;
            strcpy_s(table[m][j][k].code, sizeof(table[m][j][k].code), garb);
            memcpy(table[m][j][k].path, garb_path, sizeof(garb_path));
        }
    }
}
```

Am I initializing it correctly? or what should I correct to make it work?

Comment: `struct table_info ***table` ==> `struct table_info (*table)[COLS][DEPTH];` and `table = (table_info***)malloc(ROWS* sizeof(**table));` ==> `table = malloc(ROWS * sizeof *table);` and remove the other `malloc`s if you want a real 3D array.

Comment: [Three stars](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) very often signal a design mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size passed to `malloc` is incorrect in the following line:

```
table[m][j] = (table_info*)malloc(DEPTH * sizeof(table[m][j]));
```

`sizeof(table[m][j])` is just `sizeof(**table)`, which is `sizeof(table_info *)`.  It should be `sizeof(table_info)`, or alternatively `sizeof(*table_info[m][j])` or `sizeof(***table_info)`.

You also don't need to cast the result of `malloc`, which is generally frowned upon today (at least in C).  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) for more info.

So the following should work (in C):

```
table[m][j] = malloc(DEPTH * sizeof(*table[m][j]));
```

Comment: i am casting because otherwise MSVC gives me error, saying i cant assign a void* to a struct pointer. but I think your solution has worked. let me check it one more time and get back to you

Comment: If the cast is required, you are compiling a C++ program, not a C program.

Comment: @mch Ah, ok - I was keying in on the C tag.

Comment: @TomKarzes my comment was a hint for the OP that he probably does not write a C program ;)

Comment: you are right @mch I was compiling a c program as c++. Thanks.